# Get the selected index of combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, combobox

**This is the re-make question in order to get the better explanation and to have you understand the question clearly**

My problem is: I cannot get the value of selected index of combo box (I have tried the getter and setter function on combo box, but no success, but when I tried the getter and setter function on text box, it succeed. **This code below not using the getter and setter function on combo box, just using the pass value**

I posting the mixed images (`Login form, Wait form, Choices form and the database`):

[image]

If you can see the above image, I have entered the `username` and `password` on the `Login form`, and I have select the `Language` to `English`, and when I click `Log on` button, the `Wait form` appear and when the `Wait form` already finished loading, the `Choices form` appear and if you can see, there is text that says `Welcome, Fuhans - Administrator`, it matched properly like I entered the `username` and `password` back in the `Login form`, but something is missing, is the `Language`, if you can see in the `Choices form`, the `Language` combo box text not displaying anything **(Back then when I not using `Wait form`, the `Language` combo box in the `Choices form` display `English` as I select the `English` `Language` in the `Login form` and this image below also have `the database` for this system.

Here is the code that I am using:

**Login form code**:

```
Wait _wait = new Wait();
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";
        bool isValidPassword = false;

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.comboBox1.Items.Add("English");
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Mandarin");

            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = @Username";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                    using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dReader.Read())
                        {
                            _wait.ShowDialog();

                            UserInformation.Password = (string)dReader["Password"];

                            isValidPassword = BCrypt.CheckPassword(this.textBox2.Text, UserInformation.Password);

                            if (isValidPassword)
                            {
                                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                                sound.Play();

                                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Verified", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                                if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                                {
                                    UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)dReader["Username"];
                                    UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType = (string)dReader["UserType"];

                                    this.Hide();

                                    Choices _choices = new Choices();
                                    _choices.ShowDialog();

                                    this.Close();
                                }
                            }

                            else if (!isValidPassword)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Not Verified", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                            }
                        }

                        dReader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Wait form code**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

        private void Wait_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = 2000;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            this.Hide();
            this.Close();
        }
```

**Choices form code**

```
private Login _login;

        public Choices(Login _login)
            : this()
        {
            this._login = _login;
        }

        private void Choices_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.label6.Text = UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser + " " + " " + "-" + " " + " " + UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType;
            this.label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            if (_login.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Text = "English";
            }

            else if (_login.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Text = "Mandarin";
                this.button1.Location = new Point(155, 87);
                this.label1.Text = "";
                this.label2.Text = "";
                this.button2.Location = new Point(153, 163);
                this.label3.Text = "";
                this.button3.Location = new Point(135, 236);
            }
        }
```

**Getter and setter**

```
internal class UserInformation
    {
        public static string CurrentLoggedInUser
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static string CurrentLoggedInUserType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Hope this re-make question make you guys clear what my problem is and could help me.

Thank you!

Your answer much appreciated!

Comment: Cannot be answered until we know what Wait Form is and what is happening after Login form.

Comment: Please check the question again sir. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to pass controls to other forms. You could instead define a public Language enum with English and Mandarin as the two, and pass the enum to your Choices form based on what you have selected.

Comment: you mean like getter and setter function? or the enum is different from getter and setter? if you said it is same like getter and setter function, I already tried it and it had no success (only for the combo box, but from the text box it succeed)

Comment: No. Somewhere you define a public enum with English and Mandarin. Then when you call your second form, depending on what index you have selected, you pass the appropriate enum to your second form.